# Invalid argument exception for only partial code, the other half is executed correctly

Tags: java, selenium

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string
      Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
      System info: host: 'PC-MADHURI', ip: '10.0.0.182', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
      Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
      Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\MMADAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.kDcSxpCsqEfZ, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0.0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=53.0.2, platformVersion=10.0, moz:processID=7416.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=windows_nt}]
      Session ID: 2d456bb5-3fe3-45fe-8c6c-1222700956d8
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:272)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:96)
        at CucumberTest.check.AppTest.i_am_a_single_applicant(AppTest.java:60)
        at ✽.Given I am a single applicant(C:/Projects/Automation/check/src/test/java/SingleApplicantVast.feature:26)
```

Comment: where's the code ?

Comment: im using lates firefox: 53.0.2(32 bit)
selenium - 3.4.0
gecko-0.16.1- win32

Comment: public class AppTest{
 
 
  WebDriver driver = null;
  
 @Given("^I am a single applicant$")
 public void i_am_a_single_applicant() throws Throwable {
   //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\java\\geckoDriver\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://tst-2015.moneyou.nl/hypotheek/berekenen/bereken-je-maximale-hypotheek#");
  
  driver.manage().window().maximize();

        String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
        String subWindowHandler = null;

        WebElement btn = n

Comment: //Selecting option alleen
  driver.findElement(By.id("application_0")).click();
     System.out.println("@Given: I am a single applicant");
     
     Thread.sleep(5000);
     WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("grossIncome"));
     element.sendKeys("45612");
  // boolean status = element.isDisplayed();  
   Thread.sleep(5000);
   WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.id("housePrice"));
   element1.sendKeys("50000");  
   System.err.println("@Given :000000033333");
   
     throw new PendingException();
 }
 }

Comment: Oh god, Please include that in the post, not here!

Comment: it wasnt accepting in the post, sorry Chandler Bing

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is a timing problem 
your web driver is trying to deal with an element which is not clickable or available to send keys

I suggest replacing the

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

With

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("grossIncome")));
```

&

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("housePrice")));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with the Firefox browser from 53 version which is not compatible with the gecko driver 0.15 version. 
I faced the same issue and it got resolved when I replaced my gecko driver with the latest one that is 0.18 version.